# AngularJS loading script file with multiple templates views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angulasJS for building a webpage. I am using 2 different templates (articlesView.html, singleArticleView.html)for the same html page(blog.html) and one js file which triggers an event when it finds the position of a X element in the template(singleArticleView.html). 
I have got 2 annoying problems with it:

1) The position of my X element changes depending on the content fetched, but my js function is stuck to the first DOM structure loaded by the template. So, second time the event is triggered at the same position where the element was last time but no in the current one. I have to fully refresh in order the function can get the right coordinate of the element. It means i can not use data-ng-href to switch between views.

2)Second problem is that the script file is called in one child template (singleArticleView.html) and if I switch to another child that doesn't have that reference to the script, the js file is still working. it happens if I use an anchor element to move between them. So, Similarly I have to refresh fully to avoid that behavior.

I really appreciate any suggestion or an alternative approach.

The code for my Angular Module which defines the routes is:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("dbayonaCode", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Templates/articlesView.html",
        controller: "articlesController"
    });       


 $routeProvider
 .when("/article/:id", {
     templateUrl: "Templates/singleArticleView.html",
     controller: "singleArticleController"
 });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

});


}());
```

articlesController.js

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module("dbayonaCode");


var articlesController = function ($scope, dataService) {


    $scope.data = dataService;
    $scope.isBusy = true;


    if (dataService.isReady() === false) {
        dataService.getArticlesShortDescription()
        .then(function (data) {
            angular.copy(data, dataService.articles);

        }, function () {
            alert("could not load articles");
        })

        .then(function () {

            $scope.isBusy = false;
        });

    }

}

app.controller("articlesController", articlesController);

}());
```

singleArticleController.js

```
      (function () {

                var app = angular.module("dbayonaCode");


                var singleArticleController = function ($scope, dataService, $window, $routeParams, $sce) {

                   $scope.article = {};
                    $scope.newComment = {};

                    //Get the article with its comments to show in the template and add a new comment
                    //It uses ArticlesController.cs
                    dataService.getArticleById($routeParams.id)
                     .then(function (data) {
                         //success
                         $scope.article = data;
                         $scope.myContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.body);

                     },

                     function () {
                         //error
                         $windows.location = "#/";

                     });                    


                }
                app.controller("singleArticleController", singleArticleController);
            }());
```

singleArticleView.html ( Both of the DOM elements at the bottom of this page, which my script code is getting reference, are part of my _Layout page. I am using the library  waypoint to trigger a function when I scroll to these elements.)

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

            <div>

                <div>
                    <a href="#/" class="btn"> Back to Articles </a>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div class="full-article">

                            <div class="blog-title-header">
                                <h1>
                                    <a class="article-title" data-ng-href="#/article/{{article.id}}">{{article.title}}</a>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="blog-info">
                                <li>
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar "></i> {{article.dateCreated | date:'medium' }}

                                </li>

                            </ul>


                            <div class="blog-body">
                                <span ng-bind-html="myContent"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        .............          
                    </div>     
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>

                $(document).ready(function () {


                    $('#sidebar-container').waypoint({

                        handler: function (direction) {
                            if (direction === 'down') {
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('position', 'fixed');
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('width', '100%');

                            }
                            else {
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('position', 'relative');
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('width', '100%');
                            }
                        },

                        offset: 40
                        //offset: '80%' //-30 en la mitad del slide
                    }
                      );



                    $('#section-footer').waypoint({

                        handler: function (direction) {
                            if (direction === 'down') {
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('position', 'relative');
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#sidebar-container').css('position', 'fixed');
                            }

                        },

                        offset:10
                        //offset: '80%' //-30 en la mitad del slide
                    }
                 );


                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the JS code you're talking about? Also, are you saying that you're loading JS in a `<script>` tag inside your HTML templates? Why not write that code in your controllers?

Comment: Thanks azium. That's my code. I have tested it with the code in the controller but I've got the same behavior. Both of the DOM elements that my script code is getting reference, are part of my _Layout page. I am using the library waypoint to trigger a function when I scroll to these elements.